# How to deal with synchronous method/task using async/await

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm trying to understand how to use the .net 4.5 async/await keywords with a Task that at it's core is synchronous.  I.e. some sort of complex math calculation.  I've used a Thread.Sleep to simulate that action in the example below.  My question is there a way you can make such a method act like an async method?  If not do you just need to do what I did in the ThisWillRunAsyncTest method and do something like Task.Factory.StartNew on that sync method.  Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using NUnit.Framework;

[TestFixture]
public class AsyncAwaitTest
{
    [Test]
    //This test will take 1 second to run because it runs asynchronously
    //Is there a better way to start up a synchronous task and have it run in parallel.
    public async void ThisWillRunAsyncTest()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.RunTask()));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    [Test]
    //This test will take 5 seconds to run because it runs synchronously.
    //If the Run Task had an await in it, this this would run synchronously.  
    public async void ThisWillRunSyncTest()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(this.RunTask());
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    //This is just an example of some synchronous task that I want to run in parallel.
    //Is there something I can do in this method that makes the async keyword work?  I.e. this would run asynchronously when called from ThisWillRunSyncTest
    public async Task RunTask()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: If `RunTask` is synchronous then it shouldn't return a `Task` at all, and lifting it into a task should be done by the callers.

Comment: You might want to read this blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/10/29/asynchronous-programming-in-c-5-0-part-two-whence-await.aspx

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a general rule, if you have *parallel* work to do, you should be using `Parallel` or parallel LINQ.

There are times when it's convenient to treat CPU-bound work as though it were asynchronous (i.e., running it on a background thread). This is what `Task.Run` is for (avoid using `StartNew`, as I [describe on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)).

Synchronous methods should have synchronous method signatures:

```
public void RunTask()
{
  Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

They should only be wrapped in `Task.Run` if the calling code requires it (i.e., it is part of a UI component such as a view model):

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => this.RunTask()));
}
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The principle here is that `Task.Run` should be used in the invocation, not the implementation; I go into more details [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html).

Note that if you have any real complexity, you should be using `Parallel` or parallel LINQ instead of a collection of `Task.Run` tasks. `Task.Run` is fine for small stuff but it doesn't have all the smarts the parallel types do. So, if this is part of a library (and not necessarily running on a UI thread), then I'd recommend using `Parallel`:

```
Parallel.For(0, 5, _ => this.RunTask());
```

As a final side note, asynchronous unit test methods should be `async Task`, not `async void`. NUnit v3 has already removed support for `async void` unit test methods.